# JAXB annotation for repeating block of elements

Tags: xml, annotations, jaxb

I have the following example XML I would like to unmarshal using jaxb annotations:

```
<root>
    <AAA>
        <a>stuff</a>
        <b>1</b>
        <c>8</c>
        <BBB>
            <a>more stuff</a>
            <b>2</b>
            <c>10</c>
            <CCC>
                <a>other stuff</a>
                <b>2</b>
                <c>10</c>
            </CCC>
        </BBB>
    </AAA>
</root>
```

I would like to factor out the repeating elements in to a class, like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeName {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

Is there a way to annotate this, without having to repeat the properties in each class AAA, BBB, CCC?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AAA {
    **@WhatToUseHere?**
    private SomeName someName;

    private BBB bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already on the right track.
Your class `SomeName` is fine.

But then you need to define the other classes `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC`
by extending `SomeName`.
(If you are still new to Java, then you may want to read more about [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) first.)

By doing so these 3 classes contain all the members (`a`, `b`, `c`)
from their superclass `SomeName`.
JAXB works well together with Java inheritance.
And therefore the 3 XML elements `<AAA>`, `<BBB>` and `<CCC>`
automatically contain all the sub-elements `<a>`, `<b>` and `<c>`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AAA extends SomeName {

    @XmlElement(name="BBB")
    private BBB bbb;
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BBB extends SomeName {

    @XmlElement(name="CCC")
    private CCC ccc;
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CCC extends SomeName {

}
```

and finally the root element:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "AAA")
    private AAA aaa;
}
```

Notice also:
Some Java members are annotated with [`@XmlElement(name="something")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html)
to explicitly set the name of the according XML element.
If you would not do that, then the Java member would be mapped to an XML element
with the *same* name.
For example: the Java member `private AAA aaa` would be mapped
to the XML element `<aaa>` (not `<AAA>`).